# Заполняю БД. Выдало ошибку

Tags: mysql, sql

Ошибка следующая:

> ERROR 1264: 1264: Out of range value for column 'birthday' at row 1
>   SQL Statement: UPDATE booksdb.authors SET name='Лев Толстой',
>   birthday=1828, id='6' WHERE id='6'

[image: скриншот заполнения]

Поле birthday типа year. Если я указываю год<=1900 - мне показывает вышеуказанную ошибку. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL извлекает и выводит величины `YEAR` в формате `YYYY`. Диапазон возможных значений - от `1901` до `2155`.

Величины типа `YEAR` могут быть заданы в различных форматах:

- Как четырехзначная строка в интервале значений от `1901` до `2155`.
- Как четырехзначное число в интервале значений от `1901` до `2155`.
- Как двухзначная строка в интервале значений от `00` до `99`.
- Величины в интервалах от `00` до `69` и от `70` до `99` при этом преобразуются в величины YEAR в интервалах от `2000` до `2069` и от `1970` до `1999` соответственно.
- Как двухзначное число в интервале значений от `1` до `99`.
- Величины в интервалах от `1` до `69` и от `70` до `99` при этом преобразуются в величины YEAR в интервалах от `2001` до `2069` и от `1970` до `1999` соответственно.

> Необходимо принять во внимание, что интервалы для двухзначных чисел и
>   двухзначных строк несколько различаются, так как нельзя указать `ноль`
>   непосредственно как число и интерпретировать его как `2000`.
>   Необходимо задать его как строку `0` или `00`, или же оно будет
>   интерпретировано как `0000`. Как результат выполнения функции,
>   возвращающей величину, приемлемую в контексте типа данных `YEAR`
>   (такой как `NOW()`). Недопустимые величины `YEAR` преобразуются в
>   `0000`.

Comment: Что лучше использовать вместо year?

Comment: @БодяСкалиуш если вы хотите записывать год, используйте небольшой целочисленный тип например SMALLINT, его пределы лежат в значениях от -32768 до 32767, а занимает он всего 2 байтa.

Comment: Спасибо большое!